# Detectar la actividad de llamada de Whatsapp

Tags: android, whatsapp

soy nuevo en esto de desarrollo de aplicaciones sobre android, tengo duda sobre java de una aplicación que pueda desactiva las llamadas de whatsapp, ¿saben cual es esa sentencia o algo que identifique el notificador de llamada entrante e ignorarla?

Comment: Por seguridad y a menos que seas uno de los creadores de WhatsApp no creo que se pueda.

Answer (score 2):

Esto no esta soportado por [Whatsapp](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/28000016), por lo tanto no existe una API para lograr esta funcionalidad en <kbd>Android</kbd>.

Puedes constatarlo en la documentación:
https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/28000016